# Get Output Range in Batch Script

Tags: batch-file

I am making a batch script and have googled around on how to put the output of a command into a variable, however this code grabs the entire output, where as I only need the first 4 digits up to the colon. (in my case)

here is a an example output of debug.exe:

```
0ADE:0AC0
```

So, in this case the value of myvar should be 0ADE.
here is the code:

```
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%a in (`echo s 100 8000 74 00 5c 00  4f`) do (set myvar=%%a)
```

I think I might need the delims paramater but cant figure out how to use it with batch being how it is.

Comment: Your debug example does not match your `FOR /F` example.  I am not sure what output you want from the `FOR /F` command.

Comment: expected output: 0ADE.
 
debug is its own shell so you have to type "debug" before typing "s 100 8000 74 00 5c 00  4f`"

Comment: That doesn't explain why you have `ECHO` for the `IN` clause.

Comment: because to type text into the console via scripting you have to use echo

Comment: You are not explaining how debug.exe fits into this code.

Comment: Debug isn't a shell, it's a program so it doesn't have access to `for`. You can try to pipe the echo command to debug, but I have no way of testing this.

Comment: s 100 8000 74 00 5c 00  4f is a paramater of debug.exe but you cant type it on the same line like: debug.exe file.dll s 100 8000 74 00 5c 00  4f. that wont work

Comment: `echo %myvar:~0,5%`

Answer (score 0):

I can't use debug on 64bit windows, so untested:

```
@Echo off
for /f "delims=:" %%a in ('
    echo s 100 8000 74 00 5c 00  4f^|debug.exe file.dll
') do set "myvar=%%a"
```

Or prepare an input file for debug that also contains an exit/quit command.

Comment: hi, Thanks for the code, I am getting the following error: the system cannot find the file echo

Comment: The `for` loop is not interpreting the command `echo` as a single quote `'` is missing in front of the opening parentheses `(` to become `('`.

Comment: @micheal_heath now command prompt just shows  a blinking caret and typing anything does nothing, clicking the close button displays the program not responding dialog.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: If I understand well, you only need to snip a string. If that's the case, use ":~0,0" within your previous variable set, where each 0 stands for a index position. E.G: 
Each of the following lines will type "Hello world!"

```
set random=Hello world!
echo %random%
echo %random:~0,5% world!
echo Hello %random:~6%
```

Regarding the result of "debug.exe", maybe you can pipe its results to a temporary file, call it in the batch, and the snip the result.

As you do not share enough code, I can't properly help you, but I will suggest something like this:

```
@echo off

rem This will start debug.exe, and let's hope it allows to pipe the result to a file, as it does not always works.
start "" do.exe > "%temp%\log_file_debug.txt"

rem Wait until the output file is written.
echo Press any key once the application is finished.
pause > nul

rem Now lets retrieve the results from the previous file, and hope it have this format: 0ADE:0AC0
for /f "tokens=*" %%c in ('type "%temp%\log_file_debug.txt"') do set results=%%~c

rem As we have retrieved the results into a variable, let's snip it only for the 4 firts characters
set snip_result=%results:~0,4%

rem Your snipped code is now set in the variable snip_result. Check it out:
echo Check the result: %snip_result%

pause
```

Hope it helps.
Regards.
CM.-

Comment: Hi, I am getting the following errors the first is  a dialog box saying:windows cannot find do.exe, make sure you type the name corectly and try again. the second is in command prompt saying: "the system cannot find the file do.exe."
I tried changing do.exe to do (since DO is an internal comand), but the same thing happnes. I am getting the same error with the other suggested answer above too. Your code is on the rght track as to what I need though.

Comment: Take your time to review the code and understand it, otherwise, you may find complicate to manipulate it.
`start "" x.x` will run any archive with its parent application. In the aforementioned example, it will run do.exe if an executable named like that is placed within the same patch.
`do.exe` has to be changed by your application name, which, I belive is debug.exe.
The `>` is requesting the application results to be printed to a file.

Comment: ok I replaced do.exe with debug.exe C:\windows\system32\rshx32.dll s 100 8000 74 00 5c 00  4f but it opens a console window with the title: "ntvdm -8c0.8c4.300002" and there is just a blinking caret, hitting any keys on the keyboard does nothing.

Comment: Hmmm. I think that you will be better by using another tool, rather than a batch file. Maybe VBS or Python could help you. I did a google search reggarding that "debug.exe" (didn't know it exists), and it seems you can track it with another windows tool. Maybe one of those tools already ouput a log file, so you will only need to type it out with `for /f "tokens=*" %%c in ('type "%temp%\log_file_debug.txt"') do set results=%%~c`